# Графика в 2D SFML в С++

Tags: c++, математика, sfml, рисование, графики

Стал знакомиться с библиотекой SFML и поставил перед собой задачу изобразить в окне приложения 2 графика функций на некотором промежутке. Но столкнулся с 2мя проблемами:

1. Каким образом изобразить оси координат?
2. Как соединять точки в линии, чтобы построить график?

Буду очень рад, если поделитесь источником, в котором будет объяснена документация библиотеки на русском языке.

Answer (score 0):

Давайте подумаем, а что такое координатные оси? это просто две перпендикулярные линии. Все. Ну ок, ещё плюс по две-три маленькие линии или треугольник, что бы стрелочку сделать.

Вот документация, как  нарисовать линию https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1VertexArray.php

```
sf::VertexArray line(sf::Lines, 4); // Lines - у нас отдельные линии
line[0].position = sf::Vector2f(-10, 0); // первая линия
line[1].position = sf::Vector2f(10, 0);
line[2].position = sf::Vector2f(0, -10); // вторая
line[3].position = sf::Vector2f(0, 10);
window.draw(line);
```

все, уже есть две перпендикулярные линии.

Теперь в к торой половине вопроса. Тут можно либо рисовать кучу точек и экспериментально подобрать подходящее количество. Либо использовать метод выше, просто вместо  `sf::Lines` использовать `sf::LineStrip` - в этом случае точки будут определять точки ломанной. Да, она ломанная, но на первый подход сойдет.